# Using a function to return a count of keys within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a newbie when it comes to Python, let's just start with that.

Now that that is out of the way, I am struggling with dictionary/list problem in Python.  I have been tasked with writing a function that takes two arguments, one being a dictionary and one being a list of keys.  I need to return a count of how many of keys in this list appear in the dictionary.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def members({'name': 'Scott', 'title': 'esquire'},['name', 'age', 'title'])
    total_num = 0
    for key in dict:
      if name in members:
        total_num += 1
      elif age in dict:
        total_num += 1
      elif title in members:
        total_num += 1
      else:
        break
      print(total_num)
```

I know my syntax here is probably way off, but I'm curious if I'm on the right track here.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: when you define a function, use names of attributes.. not values... for example, `def members( a_dict, a_list)`. On the other hands, watch your indentation!!!!! it's very important in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have how to doit explained.

```
dictionary = {'name': 'Scott', 'title': 'esquire'}
list_ = ['name', 'age', 'title']

def members(dictionary, list_):
    # Define counter
    cant = 0
    # Iter over all list items and check if appear in  dictionaty.keys().
    for elem in list_:
        # Check if elem in dictionay.keys()
        if elem in dictionary.keys():
            # If true increment counter
            cant = cant + 1

    # Finally return cant
    return cant


print(members(dictionary, list_))
```

There is a tiny but important difference with the others answers, if the list where:

```
['name', 'age', 'title', 'name']
```

the mlwn's answer result still being 2. While according the OP's question *count of how many of keys in this list appear in the dictionary* is not corrent. Should be 3.

Comment: *"the others answers result still being 2"* You sure about that? You might want to run that list through my function and check ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah, you are totally right!! My bad, I will take you out of that comment. :D

Comment: I hadn't thought of defining the variables separately, and then combining them into the function.  That makes perfect sense.  Can you tell I'm REALLY new at this??  Thank you all for your helpful tips!

Answer (score 2):

or you could do explicitly ..

```
def members(a_dict, a_list):
    total_num = 0
    for a_key in a_dict.keys():
        if a_key in a_list:
            total_num += 1
    return total_num
D = {'name': 'Scott', 'title': 'esquire'}
L = ['name', 'age', 'title']
print members(D,L)

>> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to check if each element of the list is a key in the dictionary, then just check the length of the generated list.

```
>>> d = {'name': 'Scott', 'title': 'esquire'}
>>> l = ['name', 'age', 'title']
>>> len([i for i in l if i in d])
2
```

As a function

```
def keysInDict(d, l):
    return len([i for i in l if i in d])

>>> keysInDict({'name': 'Scott', 'title': 'esquire'}, ['name', 'age', 'title'])
2
```

Comment: This really changes the approach of the OP's original method. As it looks like homework, he's probably in the process of learning about functions and if/else statements. Although your answer is a correct and much more efficient way of doing the task, I don't believe it's a good idea to completely skip over the real issue at hand, which is how he thinks a function with iteration works.

Comment: shouldn't it be ... `[...if i in d.keys()]...` instead of  `[...if i in d]...`

Comment: @mlwn No it doesn't matter. The latter has the exact same meaning as the former, it will only check dictionary keys.